# How to preserve Date Modified when copying S3 files to Azure Blob Storage via Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have an Azure Data Factory which copies files from S3 to Blob Storage. I'd like to keep the S3 `Date Modified`. I set the activity `Preserve: Attributes` as seen [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-preserve-metadata#preserve-metadata) but that didn't work. The files in Blob Storage always have the date they were copied over.

Comment: I think Date modified or last modified time is not customer specified metadata.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the doc says:

> Copy activity supports preserving the following attributes during data
> copy:
>
> All the customer specified metadata And the following five data store
> built-in system properties: contentType, contentLanguage (except for
> Amazon S3), contentEncoding, contentDisposition, cacheControl.

`Preserve: Attributes` can't keep the `Date Modified`. And I don't think this can be achieved by Azure Data Factory. You can refer to [Copy Different type of file from Gen1 Azur lake to Azur Gen2 lake with attribute( like last updated)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63981373/copy-different-type-of-file-from-gen1-azur-lake-to-azur-gen2-lake-with-attribute/63985724#63985724)

Comment: Totally missed that. Thank you.